# How to rename font (family) name of variable font to comply OFL?

Tags: fonts, conversion, license, truetype-fonts

I downloaded [this](https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Raleway?query=raleway) variable font from google fonts. Since I convert the font to the WOFF2 format using [this](https://github.com/google/woff2) tool, I would change the font name due to the OFL as suggested in [this](https://opensource.stackexchange.com/questions/9673/does-converting-a-google-font-to-another-format-breach-the-license) post.

The problem is that none of the font tools I know can handle variable fonts so that I can change the name. Most programs, e.g. FontForge or Birdfont or Typograf, only open the first font style within the variable font file.

How can I change the font name of a variable font?

Comment: Doesn't Google Fonts API offer their own WOFF2 version of all fonts they have, already licensed?

Comment: As far as I could find out, no.

Comment: Hmm, it seems Google no longer has the "build-your-own-CSS" feature on their website, but I went to the [docs](https://developers.google.com/fonts/docs/css2) and attempted https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Raleway which serves that font in WOFF2 format. (The point being that licensing then becomes Google's problem, not yours... and you can also download their .woff2 files to self-host them as well.)